# How to vertical zero padding an image matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, padding, zero

I want to make a rectangle image to square image just with vertical zero padding. is there any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Image Processing Toolbox function [`padarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/padarray.html) to accomplish this. You can specify the number of rows to pad in either the vertical or horizontal directions:

```
padarray(data, [vertical_padding, horizontal_padding])
```

So in your case, to create a square image, you could do something like this:

```
img = rand(20, 40);
padsize = (size(img, 2) - size(img, 1)) / 2

newimg = padarray(img, [padsize, 0]);
```

[image]

This assumes that the padding on the top and bottom are of equal size. If they aren't you would need to use `padarray` two times to pad the top and bottom separately.

Answer (score 2):

In the unlikely event that you don't have the image processing toolbox, this is still pretty trivial:

```
padsize = (size(img, 2) - size(img, 1)) / 2
pad = zeros(padsize, size(img,2));
newimg = [pad; img; pad]
```

Note the above will fail if the difference between the number of rows and the number of columns is odd. A more robust approach is:

```
padsize = floor((size(img, 2) - size(img, 1)) / 2)
pad = zeros(padsize, size(img,2));
extraLineWhenNeeded = zeros(mod(size(img, 2) - size(img, 1), 2) == 1 ,size(img,2)); % Note that extra line will have 0 rows if it's not needed i.e. when the difference between the number of rows and columns of img is even
newimg = [pad; img; pad; extraLineWhenNeeded]
```